# How do I forward my local port on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, port, forwarding, local

I'm developing a website on my local server on my Mac. So only computers on my local network can access the site right now right? How do I set up a port forward so that my friends on other computers in outside networks can access my website on my local server?

Comment: @user75890, your last post was not an answer and has been deleted.  You should post it as a comment to this question.  Additionally, you may want to link your account at Stack Overflow to your account here at Super User.

Answer (score 2):

The port forward would need to be set on the firewall, it needs to take an external IP/Port and know to forward it to your local PC.

How to do that varies with the firewalling software/router

Comment: hi, sorry I'm ernesto11, I asked the question. So can you give me detailed steps on how to do that. I don't think i have any special firewall installed except for the default firewall.

Comment: In short, its not a simple answer, there are a lot of variables. Your mac may have a firewall on it, it may not, your network probably does, how to configure your networks firewall/router is a very specific thing. You would do best to determine what your network connectivity is, and what firewalls are there. If you're at home, its probably just an ASDL router, if you're at work, then you need your network team to deal with it.